# How to include empty folders in "s3 sync"?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

By default, it appears that "s3 sync" doesn't create empty folders in the destination directory

```
aws s3 sync s3://source-bucket s3://dest-bucket --include "*" --recursive
```

I've searched  for a ffew hours now, and can't seem to find anything to address empty folders/directories when using "sync" or "cp"

fwiw, i do see the following message that may pertain to the empty folders, but its hard to know for sure since the source bucket is pretty big and unwieldy.

```
Completed 4132 of 4132 part(s) with -5 file(s) remaining
```

Answer (score 6):

S3 has no concept of directories.
S3 is an object store where each object is identified by a key.
The key might be a string like "logs/2014/06/04/system.log"

Most graphical user interfaces on top of S3 (AWS CLI, AWS Console, Cloudberry, Transmit etc ...) interpret the "/" characters as a directory separator and present the file list "as is" it was in a directory structure.

However, internally, there is no concept of directory, S3 has a flat namespace.
See http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingMetadata.html for more details.

Knowing this, I am not surprised that empty directories are not synced as there is no directories on S3

Answer (score 4):

No way so far but a feature-request is open to add the functionality to copy also empty dirs.

https://github.com/aws/aws-cli/issues/912

Answer (score 1):

There is no official way yet.

You can use [S3cmd](http://s3tools.org/s3cmd) instead of the official AWS client, I have read it supports syncing empty directories.

Alternatively, you could use bash to add a file to empty directories:

```
find . -type d -empty -exec touch {}/empty.txt \;
```

Off-topic but related: I don't want symlinked files to be duplicated (the default when the linked file is local) but I do want to keep the structure (--no-follow-symlinks just ignores the link). So a one-liner to copy the link into a text file:

```
find . -type l -exec bash -c 'readlink "$1" > "$1.symlink"' _ {} \;
```

Comment: How do you do this with s3cmd?  I can't see any support for this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question but it is still relevant so I will answer it.

I've come across this problem and I solved it with creating a empty file inside the folder named .folderkeep which has no data in it. So when you sync it it will create the folder.

It is just to exist in a folder. It has nothing to do with the other data. And also it starts with ".", so it will be hidden to the file system.